# How can I check the setting of a bindable property inside an IsPropertyChanged method in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code that sets a label to one or another color depending on a property called IsEnabled:

```
public class LinkLabel : Label
{
    public LinkLabel()
    {
        PropertyChanged += LinkLabel_PropertyChanged;
        SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty,  "LinkLabelColor");
    }

    private void LinkLabel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.PropertyName == "IsEnabled")
        {
            var label = sender as LinkLabel;
            var newValue = label.IsEnabled;
            if ((bool)newValue)
                this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
            else
                this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelDisabledColor");
        }

    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to add another property called IsImportant

- so that if that is set to true and IsEnabled = true, then the LinkLabelColor would be set to red

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I can do this?  I do know how to add things like bindable properties but I am not sure in this case how to combine it with the code that I already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues with the other answer not working. I revisited the code and came up with this which works good:

```
public class LinkLabel : Label
{
    public LinkLabel()
    {
        SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Regular");
        SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty,   "LabelTextFontSize");
        SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty,  "LinkLabelColor");
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsImportantProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsImportant), typeof(bool), typeof(LinkLabel), false);

    public bool IsImportant
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsImportantProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsImportantProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName ||
            propertyName == IsImportantProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled) {
                if (this.IsImportant)
                    this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelImportantColor");
                else
                    this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
            }
            else
                this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelDisabledColor");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsImportantProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsImportant), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomLabel), false,/*Can remove property changed as well*/ propertyChanged: IsImportantPropertyChanged);
        
public bool IsImportant
{
   get { return (bool)GetValue(IsImportantProperty); }
   set { SetValue(IsImportantProperty, value); }
}
```

New Method **UPDATE**

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
   if (propertyName == IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName || propertyName == IsImportantProperty.PropertyName)
   {
      if (this.IsImportant && this.IsEnabled)
         this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
      else
         this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelDisabledColor");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by:  /*Can remove property changed as well*/ propertyChanged: IsImportantPropertyPropertyChanged     Are you suggesting I can remove thePropertyChanged += LinkLabel_PropertyChanged; ?  Also I notice your method has the only method name?  How about if the IsEnabled changes.  Don't we need to track that also?

Comment: so there are two things **first**: `IsImportantPropertyPropertyChanged` you need to have this if there is something specific you want to do if `IsImportant` changes, so not mandatory
**second:** If you use this `LinkLabel_PropertyChanged` then you are tracking every property change not just `IsEnabled` or `IsImportant`.

Comment: updated the method that you can add in the LinkLabel class , the method `LinkLabel_PropertyChanged` will work in code behind where you use the control not in the class

Comment: If I have override void OnPropertyChanged don't I still need to call base.OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Alan2 I'm not sure you can check, is there anything that's not working? If not then you can accept the answer

Comment: Will be checking it later tonight and will accept if all is okay.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I checked out the code and it gives an error here: protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)   Saying - Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)